# SQL - How to get the Unique Key's Column Name from Table

Tags: sql

I know how to get the columns from a table using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE (TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLENAME')
```

But how do I just return what the UNIQUE Key's Column name?

Comment: this is highly dependent of the database you use. Which database do you use?

Comment: @Xavier - as long as it's not an embedded DB, most now support the ANSI `information_schema`

Comment: It's also perfectly acceptable to have more than one unique key on a table... I'd assume you mean primary key, although that can be a composite of multiple columns

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this might work (untested):

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS TC
WHERE TC.TABLE_NAME = 'MYTABLENAME'
AND TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
```

Comment: This does not retrieve the column name as requested.

Comment: Sorry, not on my dev machine. But it's where to start. :)

Comment: FWIW, alas, not all SQL implementations include INFORMATION_SCHEMA. In particular, Pervasive SQL, formerly known as BTrieve, doesn't. Thankfully, I know for certain that Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL both do support it, and I suspect that Oracle does, too, although I have never used one of their SQL databases.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray While true, the question referenced INFORMATION_SCHEMA so it seemed reasonable that it would be acceptable as part of the answer. And it was 9 years ago...

Answer (score 21):

```
select CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME, CCU.COLUMN_NAME
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS as TC
inner join INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE as CCU
    on TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
    and TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    and TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = 'MyCatalogName'
and TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = 'MySchemaName'
and TC.TABLE_NAME = 'MyTableName'
and TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
```

Bear in mind that a table may have multiple unique constraints, each containing multiple columns. You will need to apply some additional logic to select the right one.

**UPDATE** - based on other comments...

The above query will find all `UNIQUE` key constraints. However, it will not find `PRIMARY KEY` constraints, or `UNIQUE` indexes that were created outside a `UNIQUE` key constraint.

To find the primary key, replace the last line with:

```
and TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
```

Comment: This should be the answer. 
For your information, `TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = database name`, `TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = dbo` (usually).

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
Select col.name From 
sys.objects obj 
Join sys.columns col on col.[object_id] = obj.[object_id]
Join sys.index_columns idx_cols on idx_cols.[column_id] = col.[column_id] and idx_cols.[object_id] = col.[object_id]
Join sys.indexes idx on idx_cols.[index_id] = idx.[index_id] and idx.[object_id] = col.[object_id]
where obj.name = 'MYTABLENAME'
and idx.is_unique = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The two that I found to work are the following, the 2nd one was from the original poster but without the TC.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'. That condition wasn't working

```
SELECT     col.name
FROM         sys.objects AS obj INNER JOIN
                      sys.columns AS col ON col.object_id = obj.object_id INNER JOIN
                      sys.index_columns AS idx_cols ON idx_cols.column_id = col.column_id AND idx_cols.object_id = col.object_id INNER JOIN
                      sys.indexes AS idx ON idx_cols.index_id = idx.index_id AND idx.object_id = col.object_id
WHERE     (obj.name = 'pluginUsers') AND (idx.is_unique = 1)
```

and also

```
SELECT     CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME, CCU.COLUMN_NAME
FROM         INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS AS TC INNER JOIN
                      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE AS CCU ON TC.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND 
                      TC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA AND TC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE     (TC.TABLE_NAME = 'pluginUsers')
```

Thank you all for your posts

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't DESCRIBE TABLE_NAME; do the trick?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM mbiis.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME' AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE';
```