# php recursive function issue to fetch part of string

Tags: php, recursion

I have a string which is mysql create query:

```
$str = "CREATE TABLE `custom_groupmanager` (
  `groupid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `groupname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col1` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `groupname` (`groupname`,`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `somaname` (`col1`,`col2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1";
```

I need to get the UNIQUE KEYs in array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => UNIQUE KEY `groupname` (`groupname`,`pid`)
    [1] => UNIQUE KEY `somaname` (`col1`,`col2`)
)
```

So I'm trying a recursive function but it seems to fail.This is my code

```
$tmparr = array();
$newarray = filterunique($str,$tmparr);
function filterunique($str,$tmparr){
    if(strpos($str, "UNIQUE KEY") != FALSE){
     $unitmp = strstr($str,"UNIQUE KEY");
     $tmpstr = strstr($unitmp,")",TRUE)."),\n";
    array_push($tmparr,strstr($unitmp,")",TRUE).")");
    print_r($tmparr);

    $str=str_replace($tmpstr, "", $str);

    filterunique($str,$tmparr);
    }else{
        return $tmparr;
    }
}
print_r($newarray);
```

Please help me understand where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why not regex - https://regex101.com/r/dJW7An/1 ?

Comment: you could just use regular expressions with this kind of task, example above ^

Comment: regex is fine.But i'm trying to figure what i did wrong

Comment: if  you don't want to go regex route, actually you really don't need to go recursion, just continually use `strpos`, and you'll get the strings found

Comment: $c=array();
preg_match_all('/UNIQUE KEY.*\n/',$str,$a);
foreach($a[0] as $x){
 array_push($c,str_replace("),",")",$x));
}
print_r($c);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've  revised your code. You made two mistakes:

Making $tmpstr you use `\n` wich maybe '\r\n' in windows, and add comma `,` after parenthesis`),` which is absent in the second line. As a result your code does not remove the found string, making infinite loop.

And the second mistake is that you don't return anything in If-true block.

```
function filterunique($str,$tmparr = []){
  if(strpos($str, "UNIQUE KEY") != FALSE) {
    $unitmp = strstr($str,"UNIQUE KEY");
    $tmpstr = strstr($unitmp,")",TRUE).")";
    array_push($tmparr,$tmpstr);
    $str = str_replace($tmpstr, '', $str);
    $tmparr = filterunique($str,$tmparr);
  }
  return $tmparr;
}
```

After that changing, [**code works**](https://eval.in/906824)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do what you want :

```
<?php
$sql = 'CREATE TABLE `custom_groupmanager` (
  `groupid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `groupname` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pid` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col1` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`groupid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `groupname` (`groupname`,`pid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `somaname` (`col1`,`col2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/UNIQUE KEY.*\n/', $sql, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

You'll have an array like this :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(45) "UNIQUE KEY `groupname` (`groupname`,`pid`),
"
  [1]=>
  string(39) "UNIQUE KEY `somaname` (`col1`,`col2`)
"
}
```

You can improve the regex (or use array_map to do it) to remove the trailing ",".

And : maybe it'll be more convenient to do SQL to get this informations, it seems odd to parse SQL string like that.

Check [SQL - How to get the Unique Key's Column Name from Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3180368/sql-how-to-get-the-unique-keys-column-name-from-table) if you want some examples.

Comment: In your code : you forget a 

    return filterunique